# RuntimeError: shape '[64, 3, 32, 32]' is invalid for input of size 49152

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a CNN model with Cifar10 dataset and I get this error:

```
      8       optimizer.zero_grad()
      9       input, target = batch
---> 10       input = input.view(batch_size, n_channel, 32, 32)
     11       output = model(input)
     12       loss = loss_fn(output, target)

RuntimeError: shape '[64, 3, 32, 32]' is invalid for input of size 49152
```

Can someone help me? I cant solve this error.
49512=64x3x16x16 but ı dont understand where does this number come from? (I'm beginner with pytorch)

My code:

...

```
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
      def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
    
        self.cnn1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
    
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
    
        self.cnn2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1,  padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
    
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8*8*16, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 10)
    
      def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cnn1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.cnn2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.fc2(x)
    
        return out
    
    model = CNNModel()
    model


    def train_model(model, train_loader, test_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, epochs = epochs):
      for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        training_loss = .0
        validation_loss = .0
    
        model.train()
        for batch in train_loader:
          optimizer.zero_grad()
          input, target = batch
          input = input.view(batch_size, n_channel, 32, 32)
          output = model(input)
          loss = loss_fn(output, target)
          loss.backward()
          optimizer.step()
          training_loss += loss.data
        
        model.eval()
        num_correct = 0
        num_examples = len(test_loader.dataset)
        for batch in test_loader:
          input, target = batch
          input = input.view(batch_size, n_channel, 32, 32)
          output = model(input)
          loss = loss_fn(output, target)
          validation_loss += loss.data
          predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)[1]
          num_correct += (predicted == target).sum()
        accuracy = 100 * num_correct / num_examples
    
        print("Epoch: {}".format(epoch), "\n",
              "Training loss: {:.2f}".format(training_loss), "\n", 
              "Accuracy: {:.2f}".format(accuracy), "\n",
              "Validation loss: {:.2f}".format(validation_loss)
              )
```

I need to write some more to get Stackoverflow to accept my question. ignore this sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

Think view() as a rearrangement. For example, let's say we have input like

```
input = torch.randn(1,3,32,32)
```

with declaring the input we say input should have 1 batch size, 3 channels, and 32x32 width and height.

With view, we can rearrange these dimensions like

```
input=input.view(1,3*2*2,16,16)
```

So what we've seen from here is that without changing the total number (in our case this is equal to 1*3*32*32 = 1*3*2*2*16*16) you can change your shape.

For the solution,

```
print(input.shape)
```

and then look at your dimension and then change accordingly with keeping in mind the total number must not be changed.